# Arbitrary Precision Data Types In Java

Tags: java, floating-point, embedded, cpu, cpu-architecture

Suppose my architecture supports IEEE 754. This means I'll have 24b for single precision and 53b for double precision. Now supposing in my program, I want to use arbitrary precision - suppose I want precision less than 24b so that my calculations speed up. I don't see anyway I can do this as my hardware does not support it at all. Is it possible to do, say in Java?

If not, then how do embedded computers support these? They are obviously less on the compute power so would want a lower precision.

Comment: The Java JVM specification specifies very clearly how numbers must be processed. Please explain what you are trying to do because it is not obvious (to me) what you need to know.

Comment: As kimbert said, the JLS defines exactly how computations are done. You can emulate less precise FP with integers, using a custom format. This will be slower on all mainstream architectures as all of them have HW support for FP.

Comment: *I want to use arbitrary precision - suppose I want precision less than 24b so that my calculations speed up* On what hardware?  Most CPU ISAs don't have direct support for 16-bit floats, and even if they did you'd only get a speedup from SIMD (twice as many elements for the same vector width in bytes).  Some CPUs (e.g. some x86) can save memory bandwidth by converting between 32 and 16-bit float when loading and storing, but that doesn't make *calculations* faster once they're loaded.  [Half-precision floating-point arithmetic on Intel chips](//stackoverflow.com/q/49995594)

Comment: If they supported 16b floats, why won't the calculations be faster? The precision is less so shouldn't it be faster?

Comment: @kimbert I am not talking about Java. I want to know that if an architecture supports the IEEE 754 FP standard, is there any way to work on that with precision < 24b.

Comment: you can write a set of native methods to perform basic operations over your datatype, and call them using JNI, but I'm not sure it will be faster than just use regular math. If you want fast code do not use java at the first place.